# for each loop is applied on a char array and iteration is done using a Character

Tags: java, foreach, character

I have found this program in which the for each loop is applied on a char array and iteration is done using a Character...Please explain me how it is happening??...I thought that the iteration can only be done using a char..

```
class Print{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        printCharacters("Java");

    }
    public static void printCharacters(String word) {
        char[] characters = word.toCharArray();
        for (Character ch : characters) {
         System.out.println(ch);   
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
J

A

V

A
```

Comment: This is called [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why all the downvotes, that's a legit question!

You actually had a good catch here, since the array is defined using a primitive `char` the iteration in the for-loop should do the same:

```
for (char ch : characters) {
    System.out.println(ch);   
}
```

Unless we have a good reason to do [`autoboxing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) and create a `Character` object - this overhead is not needed (and it's actually a hit in performance and a waste of memory in the heap as well).

An example for such a "good reason" is when we want to use [`generics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) which doesn't work with primitive types. However, this is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is a simple data type in Java, it is not an object like a `String`. Every simple data type has a wrapper class to use it like an object (this is needed in some situations like when using an `ArrayList` which only can store objects and no primetives like `char`). The wrapper class for `char` is `Character`, `int` is wrapped by `Integer`, `long` by `Long`, `float` by `Float` and `double` by the `Double` class.

In this special case there is no need to wrap the `char` with an `Character` instance!